# Second derived subgroup is unit, why G/Z(G) is abelian?

Tags: group-theory

why if $[G,[G,G]]=\{e\}$, then $G/Z(G)$ is abelian? ($Z(G)$ ist the center of a group $G$).

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is confusing: in the heading you are writing the second derived subgroup, which is $G''=[G',G']$, while in the explanation you work with a different subgroup. What you mean is the third term of the lower central series $\gamma_3(G)$ being trivial. If you look at $G=S_3$, then $G''=1$, while $G/Z(G)=G$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition $[G,[G,G]]=\{e\}$ says that every commutator in $G$ is central, that is, that $[G,G]\leq Z(G)$.  Therefore, $G/Z(G)$ is a homomorphic image of $G/[G,G]$, which is abelian, so $G/Z(G)$ is abelian.

Comment: Thank You, now it is clear.